# convert blob text to image and image to text

Tags: mysql, database, session

i have a field named 'picture' in BLOB format in my database and i want to save a picture in it and see that pic when i go to my index page but i don't know why in my BLOB file, there is only this link: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/tbl_get_field.php?db=swimsafe&table=users&where_clause=%60users%60.%60userid%60+%3D+13&transform_key=picture&sql_query=SELECT+%2A+FROM+%60users%60&token=6fba377987ac24bf92019e3ce578fd6d`

i just want it to show me a picture when i say:

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic']; ?>" name="picture" onClick="choosepic();" height="15%" width="35%">
```

(i have created the session and the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($_SESSION['pic']); ?>" />
```

I assume that you are storing the value from database into the session variable. BLOB data can't be read directly as they are in encoded format.

The link that you are getting is the location of the file along with the query stored in encoded form. Hope this works for you.